# Insert python list into another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have:

1. A small python list, say `list2`, `[2, 4, 6]`
2. A large, initially empty, python list, say `list1`, `[]`

What I need:

1. `list2` to be added in `list1` as a small list inside large list.
2. After addition all elements of small list be deleted.

The python code I have written for the purpose:

```
list1 = []
list2 = [2, 4, 6]
list1.append(list2)
del list2[:]
print("List 2: ", list2)
print('List 1: ', list1)
```

The expected output was:

```
List 2:  []
List 1:  [[2, 4, 6]]
```

But What I got is this:

```
List 2:  []
List 1:  []
```

Comment: It seems easier to just use `list2 = []` than `del list2[:]`, but I'm not sure if it's applicable in your case.

Comment: @qrsngky It's not applicable as above code is example only. This is asked for another project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending `list2` as a **refrence**. so when you apply `del list2[:]` it is clearing the `list` that was appended to `list1` also.

To resolve this issue you can append `list2`. **by first creating a copy** and than `appending`.

**Code:**

```
list1 = []
list2 = [2, 4, 6]
list1.append(list2.copy())  
del list2[:]
print("List 2: ", list2) #[]
print('List 1: ', list1) #[[2, 4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code. U can do it in this way as well

```
list1 = []
list2 = [2, 4, 6]
list1.append(list2)
list2=[]
print("List 2: ", list2)
print('List 1: ', list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like insert elements not references, you can use:

```
x = []
y = [2, 4, 6]
x.append(y[:])
y=[]
```